# Iterate through a QuerySelectMultipleField Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I've been trying to use a QuerySelectMultipleField to serve as a checklist for attendance. But I'm not sure about how to extract the data from the form field into the Attendance model for each member present in **routes.py**. I was unable to iterate through the form field since it threw an error that it's unsubscriptable. Also, the query factory pulls data from a different model (club_user_query() is from "Club" model) than the model I'm trying to insert the form data into ("Attendance" model). Also, I'm not sure if I can label (get_label) from a different model using a many to many relationship (Club to User) in **forms.py**.

**form.py**

```
def create_club_minutes_form(club, purchase, fund):
    def club_user_query():
        return club.members #Club to User relationship
    class ClubMinutesForm(FlaskForm):
        attendance = QuerySelectMultipleField(
            query_factory=lambda: club_user_query,
            get_label=lambda a: a.firstname + a.lastname, #pulls from User model
            widget=ListWidget(prefix_label=False),
            option_widget=CheckboxInput()
        )
        **other fields omitted for brevity**
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    return ClubMinutesForm()
```

**models.py**

```
user_club_assoc_table = db.Table('user_club_assoc_table',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('club_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('club.id')))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    school = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    schoolid = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, default=ROLES['student'])
    clubs = db.relationship('Club', secondary=user_club_assoc_table)

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer('SECRET_KEY', expires_sec)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_token(token):
        s = Serializer('SECRET_KEY')
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'

class Club(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    members = db.relationship('User', secondary=user_club_assoc_table)
    contacts = db.Column(db.Text)
    minutes = db.relationship('Minutes', backref='club')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'#Club(name={self.name!r})

class Attendance(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(35), nullable=False)
    present = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False) #set correctly
    minutes_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('minutes.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.student_name
```

**routes.py**

```
def record_club_minutes(user_id, club_id, purchase, fund):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
    club = Club.query.get_or_404(club_id)
    members = club.members
    form = create_club_minutes_form(club, purchase, fund)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            **extra things omitted**
            minute = Minutes(club_id=club_id, date=form.date.data, ..., minute=form.notes.data)
            db.session.add(minute)
            #WHERE IT GETS MESSY AKA I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET THE DATA CORRECTLY, ENUMERATE DOES NOT WORK FOR QUERYSELECTMULTIPLEFIELD
            for index, field in enumerate(form.attendance):
                    attendance = Attendance(student_name=members[index].firstname + ' ' + members[index].lastname, present= field.data, minutes_id=minute.id)
                    minute.attendance.append(attendance)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Minutes successfully recorded', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('clubs.view_club_name', user_id=user.id))
    return render_template('record_minutes.html', title='Record', form=form, user=user, club=club, members=members)
```

Comment: Why does this question have the django tag?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, so please excuse if I am wrong here, but it seems to me you want to deserialize the serialized data?

If so, you can use Flask-Marshmallow to do this. First simply commit the data to your DB and then use Marshmallow to deserialize it like such:

```
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

ma = Marshmallow(app)

class AttendenceSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', ... )

attendence_schema = AttendenceSchema()
attendences_schema = AttendenceSchema(many=True)

attendence_list = Attendence.query.all()
result = attendence_schema.dump(attendence_list)
```

If this is not what you are trying to do, please elaborate and maybe delete excess code in your example above.